# Linq GroupBy and Sum for MVVM from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have looked over other posts but cant find exactly what I need for my context. 
My program works perfectly when i don't try and add in a groupby sum using linq. I am pulling data from stored procedure using `MVVM`. My model is

```
public class RelationshipExperience
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public double Earned { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public double IncLoss { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public double Expenses { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 4)]
    public double Balance { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 5)]
    public string UWYear { get; set; }

    public int ProgramID { get; set; }

    public int InProgramChain { get; set; }
}
```

my current, working Method is

```
public IList<RelationshipExperience> sp_GetRelationshipExperience(int programId)
{
    return _CatContext.sp_GetRelationshipExperience(programId).ToList();
}
```

I want to sum up all of the columns I am using (Earned, IncLoss,Expenses,Balance) and groupby UWYear. Here is my attempt

```
    public IList<RelationshipExperience> sp_GetRelationshipExperience(int programId)
    {
        return _CatContext.sp_GetRelationshipExperience(programId)
        .GroupBy(l => l.UWYear)
        .Select(r => new RelationshipExperience
        {
            UWYear = r.Key,
            Earned = r.Sum(c => c.Earned),
            IncLoss = r.Sum(c => c.IncLoss),
            Expenses = r.Sum(c => c.Expenses),
            Balance = r.Sum(c => c.Balance)

        }).ToList();
    }
```

what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: no numbers would show up. I have found a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IList<RelationshipExperience> sp_GetRelationshipExperience(int programId, bool AllPrograms)
    {
            var output = _CatContext.sp_GetRelationshipExperience(programId)
.Where(l => l.InProgramChain == 1)
.GroupBy(l => l.UWYear)
.Select(r => new RelationshipExperience
{
    UWYear = r.Key,
    Earned = r.Sum(c => c.Earned),
    IncLoss = r.Sum(c => c.IncLoss),
    Expenses = r.Sum(c => c.Expenses),
    Balance = r.Sum(c => c.Balance),

}).ToList();

            return output;

        }
```

this works, shows results in my datagrid

Comment: How exactly did this help?  I don't see how this question or answer would ever be useful for anyone else.